# Relaunching my Widget Configuration Activity launches my App in Background

Tags: android-widget

I got a fairly complex app now and i want to include an app- widget. That works fine so far and everything is set up with content providers, services and configuration utilities.

now... i want to be able to reconfigure my widget again after the first initial configure. so my guess was to simply use a PendingIntent with .getActivity() to launch my configuration activity again. works fine so far!

```
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_news_layout);

    Intent config_intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), NewsWidgetConfigure.class);
    config_intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mappWidgetId);
    config_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent conf_penIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, mappWidgetId, config_intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.settings_button, conf_penIntent);
```

now... the problem is, that somehow the relaunch of my configuration activity brings back to front the whole app, meaning that after a "back"- press, as well as after my Configuration.finish(), the user gets back to the app, instead of the home screen.

I am sure this issue has something to do with launchModes or Intent Flags... but I can't get the hang of it right now and it's bugging me for hours.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Facing the same problem I found out that setting `android:allowTaskReparenting="false"` and `android:taskAffinity=""` for the configuration activity  will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like either NewsWidgetConfigure.class is launching your app activity on finish() or NewsWidgetConfigure.class IS your app and you will need to find a way to tell the activity that the request is coming from a widget (either intent extras or shared prefs?)

Comment: Hey... thanks for the answer. Neither one was the case. I didn't intentially launch my app from the onFinish of the configure utility nor is the configure activity my application Main.

But I actually solved it... it's somehow a hack! i am now having two configure activities... one, that is launched throught the xml- widget config after the widget is placed on the homescreen... and another one for the button press, which is absolutely the same (extends from) except that its "launchMode" is "singleInstance".