# Dialog floating on top of activity

Tags: android, dialog, widget

[image: Screen capture]

I have a very simple widget that allows the user to reconfigure the widget and select a new note.  If I had previously opened my activity and I hit the home button then click the configure button it will reopen my application with the dialog floating on top.  I have tried to clear top flag but it does not seem to work.  Has anyone else seen this before or have an idea of what I am missing?

setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: Have you tried Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP try this

Comment: can you explain more?your dialog belongs to your Activity?

Comment: Yes I have tried using the CLEAR_TOP flag, I am trying to show a Dialog Activity but I don't want it to show on top of the previously opened activities if they are still in the back stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a similar post.  Sorry about the duplicate.  If anyone else is having this issue visit this link:

[Relaunching my Widget Configuration Activity launches my App in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802928/relaunching-my-widget-configuration-activity-launches-my-app-in-background)

```
android:allowTaskReparenting="false"
android:taskAffinity=""
```